# Does IASetInputLayout check to see if you pass an already set input layout?

Tags: c++, direct3d, directx-11

I am designing a game engine in DirectX 11 and I had a question about the ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout function. From what i can find in the documentation there is no mention of what the function will do if you set an input layout to the device that has been previously set. In context, if i were to do the following:

```
//this assumes dc is a valid ID3D11DeviceContex interface and that
//ia is a valid ID3D11InputLayout interface.
dc->IASetInputLayout(&ia);

//other program lines: drawing, setting vertex shaders/pixel shaders, etc.

dc->IASetInputLayout(&ia);

//continue execution
```

would this incur a performance penalty through device state switching, or would the runtime recognize the input layout as being equivalent to the one already set and return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I also can not find anything related to if the InputLayout is already set, you could get a pointer to the input layout already bound by calling ID3D11DeviceContext::IAGetInputLayout or by doing an internal check by keeping your own reference, that way you do not have a call to your ID3D11DeviceContext object.

Comment: I ended up doing this by accident in the class that manages device states. It, so far, has worked beautifully.

Comment: I am glad it works. I hope more people find this response despite the other being marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should detect that there are no changes and so the call is to be ignored. But it can be easily tested - just call this method 10000 times each render and see how bad FPS drop is :)

Comment: Thanks. I will be testing this ASAP.